# Kentico - Dynamic Page Title Not Display Correctly in Smart Search Results

Tags: kentico

I used `{% CurrentDocument.DocumentName %}` in the Metadata > page title field. The Title tag displays ok when viewing the article itself on the browser; however, when searching through Smart Search, the results output something like below in place of the Title. I'm not sure why, is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

```
{% CurrentDocument.DocumentName |(user)myLogin|(hash)9f2b69705f777e8a884a107dfb72f681d8eb99867b6967514dbdca851b7f4309%}
```

Note: This is for hundreds of article pages, and inheriting Page Title from Parent by using the macro work best for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your transformation for search results? How do you retrieve that value?

I can see two possible approaches to solve your issue:

- go to page type -> search fields and select DocumentName as a value for Title field
- adjust search results transformation and use `<%# GetSearchValue("DocumentName") %>` instead of `<%# Eval("Title") %>`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the user who signed the macro is not in the system any longer.  I'd change the macro to simply read:

```
{%CurrentDocument.DocumentName@%}
```

Having the @ at the end will say the macro does not need to be signed.

Comment: Brenden,thanks! I did what you said and the Title (in search results) no long has the (user) and (hash) stuff, but it's still displayed as {%CurrentDocument.DocumentName@%}

Comment: What version and hotfix are you on @Michelle?